# how to get POST variable value in Java

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I need to get value of POST variable from URL.
When we inspect code on browser.
From request we have tabs Header, Response, cookies and POST.

I have email in POST tab, I need to get value of this post variable.

I am using weblogic portlet. I have request available in my cotroler.

In side request this data is uder
Request >> request >> request >> parameters >> queryParameters.

Could anyone please help on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the HttpServletRequest object. It has a getParameter(String paramName) method that can be used to obtain a POST parameter value by its key.

Comment: Try to avoid comment in answer unless you have specific detail answer. Please use comment box below and Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have pageFlowRequestWrapper. Inside this request i have 2 things _state and request of type ScopedRequestImpl. Inside this request i have another request ServletRequestImpl >> parameters > queryparameters

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue is:

```
ScopedRequestImpl request = (ScopedRequestImpl)getRequest().getAttribute("Home_6_netui:overrideRequest");
if(request!=null){
    userEmail = request.getOuterRequest().getParameter("email");
}
```

As request is wrapped so we need to get the outer request then only we can get the POST variable from weblogic netui request.